# Use arguments in Tmux script?

Tags: bash, tmux

I'm trying to write bash script, that contains the Tmux commands:

```
#!/bin/bash
# script.sh
tmux -2 new-session -s name 'another_script.sh param'

#!/bin/bash
# another_script.sh
echo $1 > test
```

It will be ok, if the `another_script.sh` has been executed with the hardcoded param value

```
tmux -2 new-session -s name 'another_script.sh param_value'
```

But when I'm trying to use a variable

```
tmux -2 new-session -s name 'another_script.sh $1'
```

value of the argument `$1` hasn't been passed into `another_script.sh`

Anybody knows what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: are you sure, it is ' not `, they are different

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Variables don't expand in single quotes. Use double quotes instead:

```
tmux -2 new-session -s name "another_script.sh $1"
```

PS: [shellcheck](http://www.shellcheck.net) would have automatically told you this.

Comment: You're right, thanks. Can you explain (or give a reference to the documentation) the difference between `, ', " in bash?